Are there rational algebraic shapes other than ellipses with area pi?
Reading this article about periods, it says there is a conjecture that rational algebraic integral giving a certain value (e.g. $\pi$) can be transformed using a set of axioms into any other integral giving the value $\pi$. Also, that this can be transformed into the area (or volume) inside an n-dimensional algebraic surface.
Given that, conjecture, it seems like that all algebraic curves giving a certain transcendental number should be related.
Let us take the set of all curves with $S_1$ topology in 2D given by a polynomial $P(x,y)=0$  with rational coefficients whose area is $\pi$, by this conjecture they should all be related. For example the ellipses which have area $\pi$ are all related by rotations, translations and non-uniform scalings.
Therefor should we expect that all these curves with area $\pi$ are related by some set of linear or rational polynomial transformations (?).
Further (more speculative) it seems like if you knew a formula for the decimal expansion (or some other series expansion) of one of these period numbers, it should theoretically be possible to use this to construct a polynomial $P(x,y,..)=0$ for which the volume gives this number.
If this is true what set of transformations would we need? If this is false, what is a counter example with an rational equation $P(x,y)$ with topology $S_1$ whose area is $\pi$ but is not an ellipse?

This doesn't meet all the specs, but $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{dx\over1+x^2}=\pi$$

We might make a distinction between transformations that invoke infinity and those that don't.

That is interesting $y=1/(1+x)^2$ transforms into a circle with the transformation $(x,y)\rightarrow (x/y,y)$

Note that my comment concerns $1+x^2$, not $(1+x)^2$.

Yes sorry, it was my spelling mistake

Here is one example in hand

Piriform curve which has an area of $\pi a b$

$$a^4 y^2=b^2 x^3(2a-x)$$

+1. Does answer the title question. Feel free to roll back and I'll put the link in a comment. I'm hoping the OP waits for a more a complete answer and one that attacks more than just the title question before selecting an answer.

So is there a u substitution that transforms   $\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$ into $\int_0^2 \sqrt{2x^3-x^4}dx$? Something I should remember from calculus class? And presumably the integral of the general piriform with variable $a$ and $b$ into an integral of the ellipse?

That is an interesting shape and certainly looks very different to an ellipse. It looks like an ellipse whose height has been scaled by y^2

This this shape transforms into a circle under the transformation $(x,y)\rightarrow (x,xy)$

Using Chebyshev Polynomials
$$m^2 y^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m}U_{n_{k}}(x)^2\right)^2 (1-x^2)$$

If this works, it's a really good answer because there doesn't seem any obvious relation of this to an ellipse.

@zooby My example works. There might be no "simple" transformation that could turn the shape into an ellipse but the change of variable $x\mapsto \cos{\varphi}$ should prove the area is $\pi$ immediately. I mean there should be uncountably infinitely many examples that can be crazier than this.
